# Dirichlet character modulo p

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characters, gauss-sums

How can I prove that if $\chi$ is a non-principal character modulo $p$ prime, then $\chi (-1) = \overline{\chi} (-1)= \pm 1$ and $\sum_{x=1}^p \chi (x) e^{2\pi i x}=0$?

For the first question, I just know that $\chi(-1)\overline{\chi} (-1)=1$, but they could be complex?

And for the second question: no idea...

Answer (score 3):

We have $1=\chi(1)=\chi((-1)^2))=\chi(-1)^2$. Since the square roots of $1$ are $1$ and $-1$, we obtain $\chi(-1)=\pm 1$. Also, $\overline{\chi (-1)}=\chi(-1)^{-1}=\pm 1$.
For the second part, I show that another sum is zero, i.e., $S=\sum_t\chi(t)$.
Note that there is an $a\neq 0$ such that $\chi(a)\neq 1$, because $\chi$ is non-principal. Let $S=\sum_t\chi(t)$. Then
$$
\chi(a)S=\sum_t\chi(a)\chi(t)=\sum_t\chi(at)=S.
$$ 
So we have $S(\chi(a)-1)=0$. Since $\chi(a)\neq 1$, it follows $S=0$.
This is also used for proving that the Gauss sum $G(1,\chi)=\sum_t \chi(t)e^{\frac{2\pi it}{p}}$ has absolute value $\sqrt{p}$.
Your sum is similar.

Comment: Thank you, the first thing was really easy (I thought to "complex"...;-)).

Comment: But the second: It is not the Gauss sum itself, the Gauss sum is $\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\chi (x) e(x/p)$, but I have no denominator $p$ in my sum - and on my way proving that the Gauss sum has absolute value $\sqrt{p}$, I have to prove that my sum is zero.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Okay, yes, your argument works, thank you!

Comment: $G(1,\chi)=\sum_t \chi(t)e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$ should be $G(1,\chi)=\sum_t \chi(t)e^{\frac{2\pi i {\color{red}{t}}}{p}}$?

Comment: @mike Yes, thank you, I have corrected it.